# Transit Visa at Dubai Airport travelling to Kuala Lumpur

Tags: visas, dubai, south-african-citizens, dxb

Do i need a visa if I arrive on Emirates flight and depart to Kuala Lumpur on KLIA? I am South African.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ZA&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=AE&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
>   for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

So no, you do **not** need a visa